# Find the volume of the region $\mathbb{R}$ lying below the plane $z = 3−2y$ and above the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried setting up the integral in polar coordinates too but wasn't sure how to set the upper limit of radius. Thanks

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581440/finding-the-volume-of-a-region-below-a-plane-and-above-a-paraboloid-triple-inte

Comment: I was wondering if someone could help me solve it in polar coordinates tho

Comment: It looks way too complicated after the second integral in cartesian

Answer (score 2):

Firstly lets note that the intersection between the paraboloid and and plane  is governed by the equation (neglecting the $z$-coordinate) $x^2+y^2 = 3-2y \Leftrightarrow x^2+(y+1)^2=4$. This is the equation for the circle centred at $(0,-1)$ with radius 2. Now it would be nicer to integrate around a circle centred at $(0,0)$ so we translate the integration 1 along the $y$-axis (we don't need to worry about the density because it's 1 everywhere). So now we need to find the volume between the paraboloid $z=x^2 +(y-1)^2$ and the plane $z=3-2(y-1)$. Now we introduce cylindrical coordinates which gives:

\begin{align}
 V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_{z=r^2-2r\sin(\theta)+1}^{z=5-2r\sin(\theta)} r dzdrd\theta
\end{align}
Because $x=r \cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. Now we carry on with the integration:
\begin{align}
 V &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_{z=r^2-2r\sin(\theta)+1}^{z=5-2r\sin(\theta)} r dzdrd\theta =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 r(4-r^2)drd\theta \\
 &= 2\pi\left[2r^2-\frac13 r ^3\right]_0^2 = 2\pi (8-\frac83)=\frac{32\pi}{3}. 
\end{align}
(that is if I didn't make some miscalculations :)